# Why does clicking a check box within a td not always work using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to click a check box within a td, using

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated("//td/div[text()='Name']/following::td/div[text()='8']/preceding::td[3]"))
```

Sometimes the checkbox is selected, however when I run `element.isSelected();` it's always `false`. When the element isn't selected, I don't get an error message thrown at all, it just passes but the checkbox hasn't actually been clicked. I can't understand why this is, I have tried using javascript and `Actions` however this doesn't resolve the issue as it only works sometimes.

I'm using the XPath to click the following TD:

```
<tr class="MuiTableRow-root jss122 undefined MuiTableRow-hover" data-testid="MUIDataTableBodyRow-37" id="MUIDataTableBodyRow-37">
  <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body jss91 jss93 MuiTableCell-paddingCheckbox">
    <div style="display: flex; align-items: center">
      <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root jss102 MuiCheckbox-root jss99 MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary MuiIconButton-colorPrimary" aria-disabled="false" data-description="row-select" data-index="37">
        <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
          <input class="jss98" id="MUIDataTableSelectCell-37" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false" value="" />
          <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
            <path d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z"></path>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body jss126" data-colindex="0" data-testid="MuiDataTableBodyCell-0-0">
    <div class="jss126">Name</div>
  </td>
  <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body jss126" data-colindex="1" data-testid="MuiDataTableBodyCell-1-0">
    <div class="jss120">Jenny</div>
  </td>
  <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body jss126" data-colindex="2" data-testid="MuiDataTableBodyCell-2-0">
    <div class="jss120">8</div>
  </td>
  <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body jss126" data-colindex="3" data-testid="MuiDataTableBodyCell-3-0">
    <div class="jss120">
      <div>
        <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
          <path d="M19 12v7H5v-7H3v7c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2v-7h-2zm-6 .67l2.59-2.58L17 11.5l-5 5-5-5 1.41-1.41L11 12.67V3h2z"></path>
        </svg>
        <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
          <path d="M3 17.25V21h3.75L17.81 9.94l-3.75-3.75L3 17.25zM20.71 7.04c.39-.39.39-1.02 0-1.41l-2.34-2.34a.9959.9959 0 00-1.41 0l-1.83 1.83 3.75 3.75 1.83-1.83z"></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I have tried other possible XPaths, like with INPUT, etc.

Comment: The handcrafted HTML makes it more difficult to understand the HTML as well as test our solutions before publishing. Update the question with the text based actual HTML.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I've updated my post with some more of the html, hopefully that's helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should try the below

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td/div[text()='Name']/following::td/div[text()='8']/preceding::td[3]")));
```

Instead of

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated("//td/div[text()='Name']/following::td/div[text()='8']/preceding::td[3]"))
```

Comment: I've changed it to this but the issue still occurs.

Comment: Can you share the actual `HTML`  as it seems to be written by yourself. OR provide the `URL` if it is public.

Comment: I've added more of the html document, it is a private page so I can't add much more.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that your XPath is returning a TD and not the INPUT *inside* the TD. That's likely the reason why

1. Your clicks aren't always successful. Selenium clicks the exact middle of the element you specify so it's possible that sometimes the exact middle of the TD hits the checkbox/label and other times it doesn't.
2. `.isSelected()` is never going to return anything but `false` when called on a TD element.

You need to update your XPath to return the INPUT. The XPath below is the modified version of your current XPath that works with the HTML provided.

```
//td/div[text()='Name']/following::td/div[text()='8']/preceding::td[3]//input
```

I would rewrite it to the XPath below.

```
//tr[./td[2]/div[text()='Name']][./td[4]/div[text()='8']]/td[1]//input
```

| XPath | Description |
| --- | --- |
| //tr | From the top of the DOM, find any TR |
| [./td[2]/div[text()='Name']] | In that TR, the second column contains a DIV with the text "Name" |
| [./td[4]/div[text()='8']] | In that TR, the fourth column contains a DIV with the text "8" |
| /td[1]//input | The INPUT in the first column |

This XPath validates that "Name" is in column 2, "8" is in column 4, and the INPUT is in column 1.

Comment: When I do this, I get : Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable

Comment: //td/div[text()='Name']/following::td/div[text()='8']/preceding::td[3]//span clicks and then your xpath returns true for isSelected, but it doesn't always click. Even when it doesn't, it returns isSelected = true.

Comment: I've added the full row of html

Comment: Given the HTML you've posted, the original XPath I posted should work but it's not how I would have written it. I've updated my answer with another XPath the way I would write it along with an explanation. When you try these, please post the full error message so I can see what the issue might be.

Comment: NOTE: One danger with using `following::td` and `preceding::td` is that it can jump to another table or row on the page which would obviously be bad and very confusing to debug. The way I've written it, all the cells must be within the same TR (in the same table).

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //tr[./td[2]/div[text()='Name']][./td[4]/div[text()='8']]/td[1]//input (tried for 30 second(s) with 2000 milliseconds interval)

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening. That locator works on the HTML you posted. Are you sure that the current page you're looking at matches with what is expected? "Name" in column 2, "8" in column 4, and an INPUT in column 1? I can't verify anything myself past the HTML you posted without a link to the page itself.

Comment: The locator definitely works, but its not clickable for some reason. I can't post the full html or the link as its a private page. @JeffC